# Vba code to search for incriminating dat files and open them in separate sheets of the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel, openfiledialog, worksheet

I have a code that allows me to open multiple files in an excel workbook, however instead of having to manually select the dat files I want to open I want to be able to loop my code so that it goes through all my files and searches for the dat files called  p00001, p00002, p00003 and so on. Does anyone know how I can edit my code to select all the files called this?

My code is:

```
Sub ImportFiles()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add


    'allow the user to select multiple files
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = True
    'make the file dialog visible to the user
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'determine what choice the user made
    If intChoice <> 0 Then
        'get the file path selected by the user
        For i = 1 To Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems.Count
            strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(i)

            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath)

            For Each sheet In wbSource.Worksheets
                total = wbNew.Worksheets.Count
                wbSource.Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
                after:=wbNew.Worksheets(total)
            Next sheet

            wbSource.Close
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are these files *anywhere* on your computer? Or do you have a folder (perhaps with sub folders) that contain all the files you want to open/use?

Comment: they are all contained within different sub folders within a larger folder

Comment: Look up how to loop through files in subfolders, and then you can do an `If` statement with the file name, for example `If Instr(1,myFile.Name,"P00") Then ...`.

Comment: You need to make clear whether P00 files in the selected folder or any P00 in any of the sub folders. In case that you have too many files, it will not be a good idea to open them with one single code. I would write a code that creates a hyperlinked list of those files, and you can click to open individually or you can select to open all of them if they are not too many. Similar codes are all over the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a Folder drill down. You can see a sample below. All you need to do is to adjust this if Statment `If InStr(File, ".dat") And InStr(File, "\p0") Then` so only the Files you want to have are beeing opend.

```
Public sheet As Worksheet
    Public total As Integer
    Public intChoice As Integer
    Public strPath As String
    Public i As Integer
    Public wbNew As Workbook
    Public wbSource As Workbook


Sub main()
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
        Dim FileSystem As Object
        Dim HostFolder As String

        HostFolder = "D:\test"

        Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
    End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        If InStr(File, ".dat") And InStr(File, "\p0") Then

            strPath = File
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
            For Each sheet In wbSource.Worksheets
                total = wbNew.Worksheets.Count
                wbSource.Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
                after:=wbNew.Worksheets(total)
            Next sheet
            wbSource.Close
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, but the code keeps finding a bug on the strPath line of the code any particular reason why?

Comment: @J.Smith there was a left over from your code. Now it should work

Comment: i still cant get it to work, it wont loop through and select the files for me it just shows the file open dialog box @Moosli

Comment: @J.Smith There is no file Open Dialog in my Code, what do you mean?

Comment: is there a way to perform both of these actions at the same time? @Moosli